# CakePHP 1.3 Return all fields but with one of the fields as DISTINCT

Tags: cakephp

What command would I use to to do a 'find' which would return all fields with the proviso that one of the fields is DISTINCT, without listing all the fields in the 'fields' array?

One can do this:

```
$this->Car->find('all', array('fields' => array(DISTINCT Car.colour)));
```

but that just returns the 'colour' field.

I want to do something like:

```
$this->Car->find('all', array('fields' => array('*', DISTINCT Car.colour)));
```

The only way to return all the fields is to list them all in the 'fields' array but I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Car->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Car.colour'=>'blue')));
```

This will return the result that you trying to get. I'm afraid this is not what you expected :)